# version compatibility of mac osx, ios and xcode to run a latest example of ios project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have been trying to run an example of IOS project. But it seems, like xcode or ios is not compatible and it generates tonnes of errors. I want to know, how to get it running. I wanna make sure, what i need to download for mac osx, xcode and ios to make all the latest code/projects run ?

Comment: It depends you need to give details of what you have - start with the fixed versions eg IOS and OSX then we can say what you need

Comment: my osx version is : 10.6.7    xcode is : 3.2.6  ios: no idea, where to look that ?

You think, these versions can run latest ( or bit older) version of ios projects. Or should i say, what i have presently is useless for development. And I must upgrade ?

Comment: In the future, please include the actual error messages when asking a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version (as of this writing) of Xcode is 4.5.2.

There have been huge changes since version 3.2.6, and you won't be able to use new SDKs or more recent features with your old version. Also, many projects on GitHub etc. are likely to be incompatible with Xcode 3.x (because they use a newer project format or features not available in your version).

In short: You should update both OS X and Xcode.

Comment: I am using MiniMac 2009 . Will it be a problem to upgrade ?

Comment: Xcode 4.5.2 is supported on OS X 10.7 (Lion) and OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). The Mac mini (early 2009) supports both, but requires at least 2GB of RAM.